# Import a pem format public key using import_key API of Azure key vault (python)

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-keyvault, public-key, jwk

Is there a way to import a .pem format public key (starting with -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- and ending with -----END PUBLIC KEY-----) into the Azure key vault in python?

Ideally, import_key() method takes the JsonWebKey format to import a RSA public key.
Is there a way to convert a .pem format public key into JsonWebKey object to be passed into import_key SDK call.
Our use case is that we need to import an externally generated RSA public key into the Azure key vault.

Is there a python module to convert a .pem format into JsonWebKey object, that can be passed to import_key method of Azure key vault?

Comment: Not sure how practical this use case is to be honest, because unless you import both the private and the public keys, then you won't be able to benefit from the features you are getting from Azure Key Vault, like encrypt/decrypt/sign/verify operations. If you want to only store the public key in a safe location, you could even store it as text in a secret inside Azure Key Vault.

If you still would like to pursue the original problem, this might help: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-keys/azure/keyvault/keys/crypto/_internal/rsa_key.py

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to import a pem format public key using import_key API of azure keyvault using python

I have created the keyvault as shown below

[image]

I have two certificates with .pfx and .cer format

I have followed the below script to import a public key using import_key API
This script I have taken from this [Github url](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-certificates/samples/import_certificate.py)  and I have changed as per my requirement

```
import os
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.certificates import (
CertificateClient,
CertificateContentType,
CertificatePolicy,
WellKnownIssuerNames,
)
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
client = CertificateClient(vault_url="https://keyhttpfrontdoor.vault.azure.net/", credential=credential)
pfx_cert_name = "newcert.pfx"
with open(os.environ[""C:\\Users\\v-kannem\\Desktop\\newcert123.pfx""], "rb") as f:
pfx_cert_bytes = f.read()
imported_pfx_cert = client.import_certificate(certificate_name=pfx_cert_name, certificate_bytes=pfx_cert_bytes)
print("PFX certificate '{}' imported successfully.".format(imported_pfx_cert.name))
pem_cert_name = "komaalinewcert.cer"
with open(os.environ[""], "rb") as f:
pem_cert_bytes = f.read()
pem_cert_policy = CertificatePolicy(issuer_name=WellKnownIssuerNames.self, content_type=CertificateContentType.pem)
imported_pem_cert = client.import_certificate(
certificate_name=pem_cert_name, certificate_bytes=pem_cert_bytes, policy=pem_cert_policy
)
print("PEM-formatted certificate '{}' imported successfully.".format(imported_pem_cert.name))
```

And then this can be converted using `jwk = pubKey.getJwk()` which will return the JWK in the most compact JSON format possible.
For importing and exporting the certificates please use the below script

> For downloading the certificates Use this [PowerShell commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-certificates-point-to-site)

[image]

***NOTE:***

The azure keyvault only support asymmetric key pair, we can't import public key as a keyvault, it will say that file does not contain private key, if we want to import public key we have to do it as secret, for that we have to create the secrets in the keyvault.